# How to make a random array in Python?

Tags: python, arrays

Sorry for the noob question.. But I can't seem to figure out how to make an array with a random set of values.

My goal is to make an array with a set of 10 random numbers (like [10, 2, 45, 22, 31, 22, 12, 88, 90, 6]) Does anyone know how I can do this in python?

Comment: What you call an "array" is going to be a "list" in Python 99% of the time. For actual arrays, use the `array` module.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the [`random`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html) module:

```
>>> import random
>>> L = range(100)
>>> amount = 10
>>> [random.choice(L) for _ in range(amount)]
[31, 91, 52, 18, 92, 17, 70, 97, 17, 56]
```

Comment: Take note that random.sample() will reduce the list you pass it, meaning it will never make duplicates. This might be what you want, but for "more" random lists use: [random.randint(min,max) for _ in xrange(len_you_want)].

Comment: FYI, This will not repeat any values, i.e., it samples without replacement, so the example given by @user2829468 is not a possible outcome, since it has `22` twice.

Comment: Thank you, this answered my question perfectly ^_^!

Answer (score 3):

Here is how you can create the array

```py
import random

ar=random.sample(range(100),20)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the simple answer that works correctly:

```py
import random
random.choices(range(5), k=8)
```